# AuthorizeNET CIM Payments

Tags: api, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I have moved Authorize.NET AIM to CIM. I have two questions to solve:

In Authorize.NET live account I can see two transaction for one transaction one is 0$ voided transaction and other one is real transaction, can I avoid 0$ transaction or it is for what?

```
$email_address = 'user' . time() . '@domain.com';
$description   = 'Monthly Membership No. ' . md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$customer_id   = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 16, 16);

// Create the profile
$cim->setParameter('email', $email_address);
$cim->setParameter('description', $description);
$cim->setParameter('merchantCustomerId', $customer_id);
$cim->createCustomerProfile();
```

In the above code can we sent customer real email instead of generated email?
will it be a compliance issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. The $0 transaction is to verify the credit card is valid before creating the customer payment profile. No, you cannot stop it from happening and you want this to occur as it allows you to get immediate feedback if a payment profile is invalid. That way you can react to it immediately rather then waiting for their first payment to fail.
2. Yes, you can, and should, send the correct customer email. That random email is just an example to show you how it works. The same goes for  the `$description` and `$customer_id` fields as well.